# Scale path to paper size or set path dimensions in pixels with RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'm trying to scale down icons that I'm rendering with RaphaelJS. Using `"transform": "s.5,.5,0,0"` works just fine, but I'd much prefer to be able to give absolute pixel values, e.g. `20px`. A nice alternative would be to get the path(s) to automatically scale to the paper dimensions. Are either of these possible?

My current code that uses `transform`:

```
$('.cog-menu-options-icon').each(function (i) {
    paper = Raphael($(this)[0], 20, 20);
    paper.path(window.icons.wrench).attr({ "fill": "#333", "transform": "s.5,.5,0,0" });
});
```

Can the path be set to automatically scale to fit the paper? Can the height/width of the path be set in pixels?

Answer (score 3):

I am not super-familiar with Raphael, but could you use the bounding box function `getBBox()` to get the dimensions, and use those to calculate the correct scale?

```
$('.cog-menu-options-icon').each(function (i) {
    paper = Raphael($(this)[0], 20, 20);

    var icon = paper.path(window.icons.wrench);
    var max = icon.getBBox().width;
    var h = icon.getBBox().width;
    if(h>max) {
       max = h;
    }
    var scale = 20/max;
    icon.attr({ "fill": "#333", "transform": "s"+scale+","+scale+",0,0" });
});
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/xUyRS/

I added code to translate the icon if the path does not have a 0,0 origin, and to center the icon.

I also found that Raphael has a bug with `getBBox` which returns bad results on multiple calls to the same path, so I am using a forked version with the fix.

Comment: i added prevserAspectioRatio to svg and tried all values, but nothing was working (no change in the positions). Please let me know why this is happening.

Comment: @rajkamal: I don't know what you are referring to.  Does your question apply to this code?  Maybe you should open a new question.